# How to transfer a money from one account to another account using paypal in android programmatically

Tags: android, paypal, escrow

I am working on an android app with eclipse ADT. I have to integrate the paypal escrow payment and i haven't find any appropriate documentation for this. So i need some sample code or some suggestions on escrow payment. It will be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal API does not support this kind of case on a mobile device. Instead, you'd need to implement the functionality from a secure backend and call the payout API.